# Spatial matching of big datasets

Tags: r, matching, spatial, spatial-index

I have a dataset with about 100000 points and another dataset with roughly 3000 polygons. For each of the points I need to find the nearest polygon (spatial match). Points inside a polygon should match to that polygon.

Computing all-pairs distances is feasible, but takes a bit longer than necessary. Is there an R package that will make use of a spatial index for this kind of matching problem?

I am aware of the `sp` package and the `over` function, but the documentation doesn't tell anything about indexes.

Comment: What do you mean by "spatial index"?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: I mean a data structure like a kd-tree, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index#Spatial_index. This data structure would accelerate lookup in the 3000-polygon dataset.

Comment: the rgeos package is usually your best bet for geometry operations. I'm pretty sure it uses spatial indexes when appropriate. Based on the GEOS C library.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/396/4630

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try and use the `gDistance` function in the `rgeos` package for this. As an example look at the below example, which I reworked from this [old thread](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/classify-point-by-nearest-polygon-tp6019714p6033521.html). Hope it helps.

```
require( rgeos )
require( sp )

# Make some polygons
grd <- GridTopology(c(1,1), c(1,1), c(10,10))
polys <- as.SpatialPolygons.GridTopology(grd)

# Make some points and label with letter ID
set.seed( 1091 )
pts = matrix( runif( 20 , 1 , 10 ) , ncol = 2 )
sp_pts <- SpatialPoints( pts )
row.names(pts) <- letters[1:10]

# Plot
plot( polys )
text( pts , labels = row.names( pts ) , col = 2 , cex = 2 )
text( coordinates(polys) , labels = row.names( polys ) , col = "#313131" , cex = 0.75 )
```

[image]

```
# Find which polygon each point is nearest
cbind( row.names( pts ) , apply( gDistance( sp_pts , polys , byid = TRUE ) , 2 , which.min ) )
#   [,1] [,2]
#1  "a"  "86"
#2  "b"  "54"
#3  "c"  "12"
#4  "d"  "13"
#5  "e"  "78"
#6  "f"  "25"
#7  "g"  "36"
#8  "h"  "62"
#9  "i"  "40"
#10 "j"  "55"
```

Comment: @krlmlr any help or is this too slow for your large datasets?

Comment: Took a bit of effort to install `rgeos` on the most "recent" Debian, see https://github.com/rundel/rgeos/issues/1. Will try later tonight.

Comment: Well, the method you suggested still computes all-pairs distances. Takes 16 minutes for my data -- not too slow, but still. A workaround is to use first `gContains` and then `gDistance` on the remaining (few) records.

Comment: I think the OP tries to find something more clever than trying all combinations of distances. Maybe some optimized matching operation based on nearest distance.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about R but I will offer one possible solution using PostGIS. You may be able to load the data in PostGIS and process it faster than you can using R alone.

Given two tables `planet_osm_point` (80k rows) and `planet_osm_polygon` (30k rows), the following query executes in around 30s

```
create table knn as 
select 
    pt.osm_id point_osm_id, 
    poly.osm_id poly_osm_id
from planet_osm_point pt, planet_osm_polygon poly
where poly.osm_id = (
    select p2.osm_id 
    from planet_osm_polygon p2 
    order by pt.way <-> p2.way limit 1
);
```

The result is an approximation based on the distance between the point **and the centre-point of the polygon's bounding box** (not the centre-point of the polygon itself). With a bit more work this query can be adapted to get the nearest polygon based on the centre-point of the polygon itself although it won't execute as quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the PostGIS code, but I'm really interested if R has similar capabilities (especially w.r.t. run time).